# SwiftUI app keeps crashing probably due to ForEach

Tags: swift, xcode, foreach, swiftui, crash

I was trying to create a Tic-Tac-Toe game using SwiftUI, but Simulator crashes whenever I try to get the code to run. Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var allMarks: Array? = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
    var body: some View {
        HStack(content: {
            ForEach(1..<3) { i in
                VStack(content: {
                    ForEach(1..<3) { i in
                        ZStack(content: {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0, style: .continuous)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    if allMarks?[i] == nil {
                                        allMarks?[i] = "circle"
                                        var randomCell = allMarks?.randomElement()
                                        repeat {
                                            randomCell = allMarks?.randomElement()
                                        } while randomCell == nil
                                        randomCell = "xmark"
                                    }
                                }
                            Image(systemName: allMarks?[i] as! String)
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I tried removing `ForEach` and pasting the contents of the `ZStack` other two times and then pasting said `ZStack` again twice and it didn't crash, so I assume it's `ForEach` that caused the problem. I'm not sure thought as it crashed a few times, too, even after I completely removed `ForEach`. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong and what I could do to fix it?

Comment: What's the error message, and what line does it occur on?

Comment: Thanks for answering @George. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: This kind of coding on view is more like Pyramid of doom, if even you got right codes, it is hard to debugging and also hard for Xcode to building! try split it to some small views!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your Image with below code, because you try to unwrap a `nil` value `as! String` so that App crashes. If you define it may be `nil` and give a default `String` that isn't assigned to any SF Symbol, it will be empty.

```
Image(systemName: allMarks?[i] as? String ?? "")
```

Comment: Note that with this approach you'll get a warning saying `No symbol named '' found in system symbol set`, which basically means that you're creating a system `Image` and you're providing a wrong `iconName` which is an empty string in this case

Answer (score 2):

This is what causes your code to crash:

```
Image(systemName: allMarks?[i] as! String)
```

You're downcasting an optional value that returns `nil`.

To resolve this you need to make sure the value is a `String` first and then you can use it safely in your `Image` view.

So change that to:

```
if let imageName = allMarks?[i] as? String {
    Image(systemName: imageName)
}
```

More information, checkout https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23